# how to align a button to the right (bootstrap 3.6)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I have tries to position the items like:

so the markup after my change [is here](https://jsfiddle.net/of13v7tz/)
[image]

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">

    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header page-scroll col-4">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/">Home</a>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/report">Report</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="searchBox col-4" [collapse]="isCollapsed">
      <form class="navbar-form  search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <!--</typeahead>-->
          <input [(ngModel)]="country"
                 [typeahead]="countries"
                 autocomplete="off"
                 (typeaheadOnSelect)="countrySelected($event)"
                 class="form-control searchInput" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"/>

          <div class="btn-group" dropdown>
            <button dropdownToggle type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
              {{selectedSearchType.name}} <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li *ngFor="let type of searchType;  let i = index;" role="menuitem">
                <a (click)="onTypeChange(type)" class="dropdown-item cursor-pointer">{{type.name}}</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

        </div>


      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="loadFromSheet()">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paste"></span>
        Load from sheet
      </button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

But it seems like this:
[image]

How can I fix this so the `"load"` button is to the right most?

Comment: 11k rep, 1000+ questions, and you still don't know that you need to include your code directly in the question... is this really your own account?

Comment: `class="pull-right"`

Comment: @musefan everytime i add the code in the question people ask me to write it in a js-fiddle

Comment: @EladBenda: jsfiddle is useful to *support* your question as it's easier for us to test and fix, but you still should include the original code in the question

Comment: @AlekseySolovey where do you mean?

Comment: @EladBenda the button of course, that's what you are moving, bootstrap will deal with CSS for you, if you have more classes added on your button, you can simply extend it with spaces in between: `class="btn btn-primary pull-right"`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey but my problem is that the button is in new row. I want it all to be in the same row

Comment: @EladBenda please add a suitable jsfiddle ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the `col-md-4` to `col-md-3` or less and manipulate the spacing between the buttons with `margin-left` property on the `Load` button. You are probably pushing the `button` to the next row, so check the `paddings` and `margins` on the CSS properties surrounding the other elements if not finding success.

Hope this helps.